# Div toggle not working after opening a Colorbox

Tags: colorbox, jquery

I was not able to find this answer by myself and I apologize if my search was not deep enough.

After so much time I've been lurking in stackoverflow, I finally have the chance to drop my own question (actually it makes me sad as I'm fairly happy to show no one how dumb I am.)

I'm working on this website http://italianliving.fi (pick english language) and by far everything I needed is working as I think it's supposed to. My issues comes with catalogs page, after I open one colorbox to display some external content, my footer seems not working as supposed to. There's a [ + ] at the bottom right which is supposed to open/close the footer; it works well until I call any colorbox, after that call it goes messed up, it slides the footer up but as far as it opens it, it closes it as well. My code for that is:

```
$('#footer_toggle').click(function(){
        if ($(this).text()== "[ + ]")
        {
            $(this).text("[ - ]");
            $('#footer').animate({ 'height': '240px' }, 400);           
        } else {
            $(this).text("[ + ]");
            $('#footer').animate({ 'height': '20px' }, 400);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

but I'm fairly sure the problem is with Colorbox itself. Any hint about how to proceed? Any other way to toggle the footer otherwise? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cards (i.e. http://italianliving.fi/pages/info_card.php?b=verysofa&lang=en) include the code.js file, but do not include the colorbox plugin. This issues an error.

I don't know if this is the source of the footer problem, but try fixing that first.

**EDIT**: Seems that you attach the click handler twice. When the colorbox subpage opens, it fires code.js again, which attaches the second click handler to #footer_toggle.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for your answer. Why do I need to add a colorbox plugin in a page where I am not calling it? I mean, I need from the catalogs page to use the colorbox, but in the info_card.php page itself there is no use for it :/ Anyway I tried but I'm still having the issue :<

Comment: @Paprika you are calling it in code.js: $(".card").colorbox({ innerWidth:870, innerHeight:600});. I'll try to look at the issue once again.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense! I didn't think of that as an issue but I should pay more attention when I use one .js file with my own code. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, as you told me what was I doing wrong (double click handler as the code was loaded twice) I just splitted the part of jquery code I needed in the info_card.php page in another js file and left the code.js loaded only into the main page. Thank you very much! You're my hero of the month! Shame on me for the stupid mistake (in which I already stepped once back in past while loading .js files within ajax, but I couldn't have figure it), but truly grateful thanks to you and your time spent on my case! Kiitoksia paljon! :)

Comment: @Paprika I'm happy to be of help :)